# How to convert any city/country combo to timezone in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Given a city and country, how do you find it's timezone correctly.

Comment: There is no native builtin function, but surely you'll be able to find a library that does it.

Comment: i couldn't find one

Comment: yes, all of them are asking for coordinates. None that takes a city/country only

Comment: don't bother me if you have no intention of answering the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use google API for this see [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/start).

The Location of your city/country should be in (longitude, latitude)

Comment: i want to avoid google api. beside timezones aren't changing daily so there could be npm package with city, country to timezone?

Comment: I know a npm package but it use google api also the best and free alternative is this api : https://timezonedb.com/api

Comment: Usually every year governments around the world make changes to timezones. The latest version for 2018 is `e`, which means that there have been 5 changes this year.

Comment: So what is the somewhat reliable way to get city, country to timezone then? it's not necessary to be upto date by day or even months.

Comment: Yes timezone and generally  dates are complicated to handle the best way, in my opinion, try to download raw data (sql or csv ..) and try to make a simple interne API to get data

Comment: thanks, that seems to be the only way. So for now I'll go with google maps api, and then continue researching this.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed momentjs is the best library for times/dates. Let me know if you are still looking for this answer, and I can help :)

Thank you very much!